# ffprobe unable to read a file but other software can

Tags: windows, powershell, ffprobe

I'm encountering a strange issue and I'm wondering what the cause is. I have a file, and it definitely exists:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout\Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E03.An.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.A.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.And.An.Angry.Elf.mkv'


    Directory: \\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
------        26/01/2022   6:35 AM      411768981 Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E03.An.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.A.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.And.An.Angry.Elf.mkv
```

But when I try to pass it to `ffprobe` it gives an error:

```
ffprobe '\\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout\Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E03.An.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.A.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.And.An.Angry.Elf.mkv'
ffprobe version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
\\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout\Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E03.An.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.A.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.And.An.Angry.Elf.mkv: No such file or directory
```

I also tried passing it to `notepad` and as expected it took a while to open and then appeared as garbage.

I can open other files in the same directory without incident, so it's not that `ffprobe` is having any trouble accessing the SMB share:

```
ffprobe '\\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout\Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E01.Episode.1.mkv'
ffprobe version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '\\192.168.10.201\Media\TV\Life With an Ordinary Guy Who Reincarnated Into a Total Fantasy Knockout\Life.With.an.Ordinary.Guy.Who.Reincarnated.Into.a.Total.Fantasy.Knockout.S01E01.Episode.1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:23:50.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2561 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 7983952
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:50.014000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 34286
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1427145548
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 hevc_nvenc
      DURATION        : 00:23:50.221000000
  Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 128000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:50.070000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 61588
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 22881130
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:23:50.070000000
  Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English subs
      BPS-eng         : 192
      DURATION-eng    : 00:23:37.500000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 489
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 34020
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: no_variable_data
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:23:49.990000000
  Stream #0:3: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Roboto-Medium.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:4: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:5: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : arial.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:6: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : arialbd.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:7: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : comic.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:8: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : comicbd.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:9: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : times.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:10: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : timesbd.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:11: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : trebuc.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:12: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : trebucbd.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:13: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : verdana.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
  Stream #0:14: Attachment: ttf
    Metadata:
      filename        : verdanab.ttf
      mimetype        : application/x-truetype-font
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 4
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 5
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 6
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 7
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 8
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 9
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 10
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 11
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 12
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 13
Unsupported codec with id 98304 for input stream 14
```

I can easily rename this file to avoid the problem, but I'd like to know which other files this might affect.

I've tagged this as PowerShell (because that's where I'm testing it) but I also see the same issue if I launch ffprobe using NodeJS `child_process`.

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, it appears `ffprobe` supports a [maximum path length of 259 characters](https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/91634-problem-long-pathslong-filename-259-characters-ffprobe-error/).

I thought that since Windows has supported longer paths for a long time, this would no longer be worth worrying about. But I guess software has to be updated to support the long paths.

Comment: Test this theory by trying URLS just above and below the limit. The ffprobe error you pasted shows the entire path.

Comment: It turns out you can get around this limitation using symlinks. If you create a short-pathed symlink to a long-pathed file, ffmpeg can read the file via the symlink. This works across filesystem boundaries as well. (I was able to use a symlink on my dev PC to read a long-pathed file on an SMB share)

Comment: Assuming your drive has the 8.3 filenames option enabled, you could also get and use the short filename.